# Why can't std::tuple be element-wise constructed with a std::tuple of compatible types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stdtuple, boost-tuples

I can't initialize `std::tuple` elements element-wise from a `std::tuple` of compatible types. Why doesn't it work as with `boost::tuple`?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    // error: cannot convert 'std::tuple<int>' to 'int' in initialization
    template <typename U>
    Foo(U &&u) : val(std::forward<U>(u)) {}

    T val;
};

int main()
{
    boost::tuple<Foo<int>>{boost::tuple<int>{}};    // ok

    auto a = boost::tuple<int>{};
    boost::tuple<Foo<int>>{a};                      // ok

    std::tuple<Foo<int>>{std::tuple<int>{}};        // fails with rvalue

    auto b = std::tuple<int>{};
    std::tuple<Foo<int>>{b};                        // fails with lvalue
}
```

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6119c5a308881705) (GCC or Clang and libstdc++ does not compile, however **Clang and libc++ compiles without errors**)

---

`std::tuple` is not doing element-wise construction and it instantiates `Foo<int>::Foo<std::tuple<int>>` instead of `Foo<int>::Foo<int>`. I thought [`std::tuple::tuple` overloads no. 4 and 5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) were exactly for that purpose:

```
template <class... UTypes>
tuple(const tuple<UTypes...>& other);

template <class... UTypes>
tuple(tuple<UTypes...>&& other);
```

Note:

> Does not participate in overload resolution unless
> `std::is_constructible<Ti, const Ui&>::value` is `true` for all `i`.

`std::is_constructible<Foo<int>, int>::value` is `true`. From the GCC template error, I can see that overload no. 3:

```
template <class... UTypes>
explicit tuple(UTypes&&... args);
```

is selected instead. Why?

Comment: Okay, it does not work with `-std=libstdc++`, but works with `-std=libc++` on Clang. Must be an implementation issue.

Comment: Please file a bug in gcc's bugzilla.

Comment: This question will still give valuable information for those who will run into same problem. It will tell them that problem is with standard library implementation and not in their code. There are many common dupe targets which are explanation of the particular implementation bug (MinGW and `stoi` for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overloads (4) and (5) are poorer matches than (3) when passed a `tuple&` : they are `const&` and `&&` overloads, while (3) matches exactly through the magic of perfect forwarding.

(3) is valid because your `Foo(U&&)` constructor is overly greedy.

Add SFINAE checks to `Foo(U&&)` so that it fails to match when it fails to build:

```
template <class U,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U,int>{},int>* =nullptr
>
Foo(U &&u) : val(std::forward<U>(u)) {}
```

The rvalue case should, however, work or be ambiguous.  Looking at the error log of your live example, the only error I see is with the lvalue one.

Comment: Wow, that works! (I changed it to `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>`) Why is there a difference between libstdc++ and libc++? Is this an implementation detail, not specified by the standard? Should we report it and to whom?

Comment: For the matching issue: `const auto b` still reproduces. You need to report this to libstdc++ (i.e. gcc's bugzilla). In addition, you may want to ask on the isocpp.org forum about adding a constructor that takes a non-const tuple lvalue, so it is a better match.

Comment: @logic thanks for fixing the typos, but the `class=` solution is worse than the `int*=nullptr` one.  In the case of multiple overloads, `class=` fails, while `int*=` does not.

Comment: @Yakk Mainly I wanted to involve `T` instead of `int`. Does it have to yield `int*` in this case? Can't it be `void*`?

Comment: @Yakk And the rvalue case also produces an error, it's there.

Comment: @LogicStuff `void*` is not a legal template non-type parameter type under the standard.  `int*` is.  We always set it to `nullptr`, it only exists for SFINAE reasons, and it is a better SFINAE system than the `class=` pattern.  The `int` could be *any non-void type*, it just happens that C++ bans `void*` in this particular case.  Some compilers fail to enforce that ban, but I believe in writing standard-compliant code when the cost is 4 extra characters.  Again, that `int` type is *never used*.

Comment: This answer is not clear enough IMHO. @Yakk, can you please edit the question to denote which items are (1), (2)... (5) respectively?

Comment: @ein references to the OP's linked cppreference page.  Uncertain of legality if copy paste repeating here; but should be edited into question IMHO.