# C++ std::valarray member variable unexpected change

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` whose constructor takes as one of its arguments as an [std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)[^1], however I have found that its values change to large random numbers once the constructor has finished.

As an aside, there could be an issue with my getters and setters, which I just started using in the cotext of C++ with the help of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760777/c-getters-setters-coding-style#760877) and `18.3.5 Accessor Functions` from [Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html).

Stroustrup's format of `constexpr double real() const { return re; }` is what my example ended up using, however without `constexpr` since my class didn't like it (I'm trying to understand [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const) but still haven't got it yet).

A comment on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50815147/6267719) of my question by user [deidei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5212827/deidei) says that `std::valarray` is "dynamic", which I guess here means that you can resize it.  That might bring issues when it comes to memory, and I think that my values might have been overwritten somehow due to this fact.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
  A(std::valarray<int> b, std::vector<int> c)
  {
      std::cout<< b[0]  << std::endl;
  };

  std::valarray<int> get_b() const {return b;};
  std::vector<int> get_c() const {return c;};

private:
  std::valarray<int> b;
  std::vector<int> c;
};

int main()
{
  std::valarray<int> b = {1, 3};
  std::vector<int> c = {4, 2, 8, 17};

  A a(b,c);
  std::cout<< a.get_b()[0] << std::endl; // returns a random large number such as 26618992

  return 0;
}
```

What issue might be causing this problem?

[^1]: (inspired by the [answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50815147/6267719), for those of you playing along at home)

Comment: You didn't initialize your `std::valarray` and `std::vector`.

Comment: What do you mean by initialise? My understanding was that since the constructor takes `b` and `c` as arguments then they will be assigned to member variables of the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding was that since the constructor takes b and c as
>   arguments then they will be assigned to member variables of the same
>   name

This is incorrect. You can initialize member variable via member initializer list, via default initialization or by assigning values directly in the body of constructor. For example:

```
A(std::valarray<int> b, std::vector<int> c)
  : b(b), c(c)
{...
```

or

```
private:
  std::valarray<int> b = {1, 3};
  std::vector<int> c = {4, 2, 8, 17};
```

or

```
A(std::valarray<int> b, std::vector<int> c)
{
    this->b = b;
    this->c = c;
    ...
```

You have done none of the above, so your `valaray` of `int`'s is size of 0. When you return its copy and trying to access non-existing element

> // returns a random large number such as 26618992

you get some garbage value from the memory.